# Drawing the given natural number

Tags: ruby

I am trying to make a function that given a particular natural number it is supposed to be printed as an ASCII art like number.

Let's say if I call `ascii(50)` something like this should appear:

```
@@@@@ @@@@@
@     @   @
@@@@@ @   @
    @ @   @
@@@@@ @@@@@
```

I did this:

```
$numbers = {
    0 => "@@@@\n@  @\n@  @\n@  @\n@@@@\n",
    1 => "   @\n  @@\n @ @\n   @\n   @\n"
}

def ascii n
    n.to_s.each_char { |chr| puts $numbers[chr.to_i] }
end

ascii 100
```

But I quickly found out that this doesn't work because it is printing each number at a time, while it should be printing each line at a time to prevent the line break.

Honestly I have no clue how to do this, any ideas?

Comment: Each number has 5 lines, store them in an array then run along the input string printing each line1, line2 ... line5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can break you variable `$numbers` in arrays of 4 or 5 segments, and then change your function `ascii` to print each segment one by one. You can try it out I guess.

Comment: then should I store each number as a list of a number of segments?

Comment: Yes, for 0 it can be ["@@@@", "@  @", "@  @", "@  @", "@@@@"]